# CakePHP Calling a Plugins Model in the App's Controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

I am building a plugin and have certain methods in the Model of the Plugin.

From the Controller of the App lets say Users Controller i wanna call a Model from the Plugin.

How do i access the Plugins Model ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$this->loadModel('PluginName.ModelName');
```

whats the big deal?

Comment: ah .. thanks.. i was trying to figure how to reference it. Any idea how to use relative paths inside the plugin ?

Comment: This is only generating a AppModel reference for me.

Comment: works fine now. ;) Missed right association config with plugin prefix.
In my case i'm generating a category navigation in the PluginAppController therefore it is present on the product and product category page.

Comment: Is it possible that cake load model automatic ?

Comment: CakePHP3 Source: https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/plugins.html#plugin-models